# New Android keyboard behaving unexpectedly in certain apps

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am a linguist, not a programmer, sorry. I was asked and am adapting a keyboard for a minority language in Africa. I have spent a lot of time on this and am willing to learn more and to dig deeper.

I am using the latest Android Studio in Windows 10 and am working from a code sample from Google here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard?autodive=0%2F

I managed to adapt this sample to our local language and compile and install in a several different phones from our team and all the new characters in the alphabet are working fine (ǝƎ ŋŊ ɖƉ ɔƆ ɛƐ ɩƖ ʊƱ). No problems here, this is just background for those who like that.

The **unexpected behaviour is sadly with several existing keys, which I have not altered**: apostrophe, quotation marks, hyphen, etc. Those are characters which to me "are too active"; possibly an escaping-problem or something the like.

When using my new keyboard in WhatsApp I can type any text just fine, until I need (for example) an apostrophe. Then the apostrophe will delete any alphabet-letter backwards until it hits a "resisting character" (those are space, full stop, comma and some others) and then it will show itself. Example sentence: "Three pigs' house."

I am typing this:

```
Three pigs
```

then I hit apostrophe and am expecting this:

```
Three pigs'
```

but instead I get this:

```
Three '
```

You can see how the apostrophe has deleted "pigs" and has been stopped by the space behind "Three". The same happens for - and for " and for a few other "bad keys".

I have this unwanted behaviour in several "powerful apps" like WhatsApp and Telegram but NOT in a simple text editor like this one:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxistar.textpad

I double-checked and **compiled the original sample keyboard: It shows the same bad behaviour** in WhatsApp, Telegram etc. but not in Simple Text Editor.

So the Google sample SoftKeyboard is having issues. I quote their doc:

> Example of writing an input method for a soft keyboard.  This code is
>     focused on simplicity over completeness, so it should in no way be considered
>     to be a complete soft keyboard implementation.  Its purpose is to provide
>     a basic example for how you would get started writing an input method, to
>     be fleshed out as appropriate.

I would like help please:

- Is this really a problem with the keyboard, or is the fault with WhatsApp etc. for "doing too much" with the characters being sent by the keyboard?
- Or how can I find out where the deleting is happening? (Since this is only an input method, the Android Studio's debugging tools do not yet work for me.)
- Is there a forum, where I can get help for that specific SoftKeyboard?
- Any input to help me to change my self-made keyboard so that it behaves normally in any App which needs text-input, even WhatsApp, Telegram and the like.
- Or is there another working template out there, which I could use to make a working soft keyboard for our language. Since I am not a pro, I am hoping for something that I can import into Android Studio for adapting.

Please do not yell at me. Any input and any help is welcome. I can upload my files, but the behaviour can be observed from the original SoftKeyboard files (see my first link at top). If you can type your own language, please be grateful. My people would also love to write their language in WhatsApp. Thank you.

First update:
I have looked over the main Keybaord.java file and have changed

```
mPredictionOn = true;
```

to

```
mPredictionOn = false;
```

for

```
case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
```

This has helped to calm the unexpected behaviour but has also lost some of the functionality. And the caps state is no longer auto-undoing like it is meant to be after user hits one capital letter.